# How to Launch two session(App and Mobile Browser) in single appium server?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, appium-ios

Hi I have this iOS native app functionality that needs to automate in Appium-Ruby + Cucumber.

After completing the registration flow(Signup), i need to put the app in background and open safari mobile web browser,then Go to Mailinator.com and activate my account.

Could anyone help me in how to handle this?

I am new to Appium-Ruby+Cucumber.

I am using Appium 1.6 version

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple alternative solutions to this rather than getting into the complications of opening the browser activity and leaving the app context in your test case..

1) Would be to integrate webdriver for browser within your appium test suite, maybe use phantomjs so the browser is headless.

Eg:

```
def activate_my_account
  browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:phantomjs)
  browser.get("http:://mailinator.com")

  <perform your action here>

end
```

2) Use a api driven mail client to get the latest email using api matching the subject line. Strip out the url from the email body and use hit the url. There is no browser involvement in this solution.

3) Get the token from database and create the validation url on the fly and hit the url using curl or http or rest client in ruby. Again this is no browser involvement solution.

Let me know in the comments if you face any issues!!
Hope it helps!!